# How to make this work when there are many itemdiv?

Tags: jquery

I need your help in solving this

This is my fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/47/

I am showing the Topping Count for Ice Cream (Initially zero).

Once you are in fiddle , click on Strawberry Or  Choclate and you see that the Topping  count **Increases** Or **decreaes** each time as you click them  .

For one itemdiv it is working fine , but how can i deal with this when there are many itemdiv ??

Sorry for the title , i couldn't able to think of a better one

This is the listener when clicked on toppings items

```
var id = 71;
var i = 0;
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {

    if($(this).hasClass("tpActive"))
    {
        i = parseInt(i)-1;
        $(this).removeClass("tpActive");
        $("#"+id+".topp span").text(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i = parseInt(i)+1;
        $(this).addClass("tpActive");
        $("#"+id+".topp span").text(i);
    }


});
```

Comment: if i understand your question, may modulus(%) helps

Comment: Looking at the HTML in the fiddle...  ids have to be unique.  You have an id of "71" for both `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks , What i know of Modulus means , it is useful during division operations ?? Is that what you are refering to ?

Comment: @Ballbin , I can generate unique id;s for the anchor tag , but how can that solve my problem here ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e56TY/48/ is it you looking for?

Comment: @marathonman , i was refering that what if i had another <div class="itemdiv" data-role="collapsible"> ?? not another section . Sorry for the confusion if its not proper in my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is that you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MSGZ8/1/

You have to be aware that there can be no more than one element with the same id. And javascript have modified:

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function(e) {

    if($(this).hasClass("tpActive"))
    {
        var element = $("#"+$(this).attr('data-id')+".topp");
        var count = parseInt(element.attr("data-count"))-1;
        element.attr("data-count", count);
        $(this).removeClass("tpActive");
        element.find("span").text(count);
    }
    else
    {
        var element = $("#"+$(this).attr('data-id')+".topp");
        var count = parseInt(element.attr("data-count"))+1;
        element.attr("data-count", count);
        $(this).addClass("tpActive");
        element.find("span").text(count);
    }

});
```

Hope that helps! :)